# Locating the quadrant containing a point on an n-sphere

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ on an [n-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere). Suppose I divide the n-sphere into 4 sections (I think this makes sense in $n$ dimensions), how do I know which section $x$ lies on?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense in n dimensions unless n=2. What are the 4 quadrants in 3 dimensions? You can talk of the 8 octants instead, and the 2^n orthants in n dimensions (it's an $(n-1)$-sphere, BTW), and if *that's* what you want, then the answer to your question is simply to look at the signs of the coordinates in x.

Comment: @Shreevatsa does it make sense to say "if I split a sphere into 8 equal hemispheres" ?

Comment: @Shreevatsa: In 3 dimensions, you have 2 axis aligned planes dividing the sphere into 4 quadrants (one plane divides it into two hemispheres and the other divides each hemisphere).

Comment: @Shreevatsa: Also, is (n-1) in LaTeX? If so, how did you format it? I couldn't find any formatting tips regarding LaTeX!

Comment: @Jacob: Just use dollar signs, e.g. `$` `(n-1)` `$` -> $(n-1)$.

Comment: @KennyTM: Excellent! I thought `$x$` didn't work when it didn't appear on the preview. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob: Actually if you wait for 4 seconds the equations will appear.

Comment: @KennyTM: Exactly. This site just became a lot more awesome :)

Comment: Whoops I thought of quadrant as octant implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a rephrasing of ShreevastasR's answer; no credit to me.  It does make sense to divide an $n$-sphere into quadrants, as you explain in $\mathbb{R}^3$: partition by two coordinate planes.
But then deciding which quadrant is, as ShreevastasR says, simply looking at the signs of the coordinates of $x$.  If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both positive, you are in the first, $++$, quadrant;
if $x_1$ is negative and $x_2$ positive, you are in the second, $-+$, quadrant. And so on.  If instead you partition the sphere into $2^n$ orthants, then you consider all the signs of the coordinates of $x$.

Comment: My understanding from you question is that you have $x$ in your hands, presumably in coordinate form.  So you look at the first coordinate, the second, the third, etc.  I guess I don't understand your question!