# Center of mass of an $n$-hemisphere

Tags: geometry, physics

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/locating-the-quadrant-containing-a-point-on-an-n-sphere).

Note that I'm using the [geometer definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html) of an $n$-sphere of radius $r$, i.e.$ \\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|_2 = r  \\} $

Suppose I have an $n$-sphere centered at $\bf 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with radius $r$ which has been divided into $2^k$ orthants by $k$ axis-aligned hyperplanes (note, $k \le n$) in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ passing through $\bf 0$. For e.g., if $k=1$, we have $2$ $n$-hemispheres.

Here's the **question**: how do I find the center of mass of such an orthant? Or (since I'm still working on it), how would you find the center of mass of an $n$-hemisphere?

Comment: Is the mass concentrated on the surface, or uniformly distributed *inside* the sphere?

Comment: @Anton: In reality, there is only the surface. But I figured, the center of mass would be the same as if it were uniformly distributed inside the sphere --- is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It does make a difference whether you're cutting up a solid ball or a shell. The center of mass will be closer to the origin if it's a solid ball. You can see this intuitively by thinking about the cases $n=k=2$ or $n=k=1$.

Comment: @Anton: Thanks, but after checking it out, I see that an $n$-sphere actually refers to the surface of a ball so I suppose the question is still correct?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't k hyperplanes divide it into 2^k orthants?  e.g., if n=2, 2 lines divide the plane into 4 quadrants.

Comment: @Isaac: Yes, you're right. I've fixed it now.

Comment: To supplement Anton's point with a calculation: the center of mass of a unit-radius semicircle is $2/\pi \approx 0.64$ whereas of the half disk bounded by that semicircle it is $4/(3\pi) \approx 0.42$: closer to the origin as he said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One finds the centre of mass for these bodies just as one
does for any body, by integration.

The $x_i$-coordinate of the centre of mass of a region $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$
is
$$\frac{\int_A x_i\ dx_1\cdots dx_n}{\int_A\ dx_1\cdots dx_n}.$$
Here the region might as well be that between the planes $x_n=a$ and $x_n=b$
in the sphere of  radius $r$ centred at the origin. Using the symmetry
of $A$ this ratio of integrals equals
$$\frac{\gamma_{n-1}\int_a^b x_n(r^2-x_n^2)^{(n-1)/2} dx_n}
{\gamma_{n-1}\int_a^b (r^2-x_n^2)^{(n-1)/2} dx_n}$$
(in the $x_n$ direction) where $\gamma_{n-1}$ is the volume of the $(n-1)$-dimensional
unit ball (and obligingly cancels). These integrals can be attacked by
trig substitutions.

**Edited**
It's now clear that my original interpretation of your question
was wrong. However it's still not clear whether your centre of mass
is for a solid orthant or its curved surface. In any case if your orthant
is defined by the conditions $x_1,\ldots,x_k\ge0$ then its centre
of mass has the form $(a,\ldots,a,0\ldots,0)$ where $a$ depends on $r$
and $n$ but **not** on $k$. One sees this from the symmetry of the problem.
Thus the problem reduces to the hemispheric case. In the solid case the
answer is
$$a=\frac{\int_0^r x(r^2-x^2)^{(n-1)/2} dx}
{\int_0^r (r^2-x^2)^{(n-1)/2} dx}$$
while in the "shell" case it is
$$a=\frac{\int_0^r x(r^2-x^2)^{(n-3)/2} dx}
{\int_0^r (r^2-x^2)^{(n-3)/2} dx}$$
(if I've done my sums right).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated my question to add that the hyperplanes pass through the origin. How would this change $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I really appreciate it and I love this place :)

Comment: At which coordinate does the $0$s begin in $(a,\dots,a,0,\dots,0)$?